# How to get insights for separate "Like" button(s), not for whole domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have put a like button on my web page which is dynamically linked to different Facebook fan pages. I have checked the insights pages of Facebook but it gives an overall count of button clicks from my site. Is there a way to get more detailed information like how many users clicked which Like button?

Facebook documentation mentions a ref tag that can be added to Like button code, however this tag does not show up in insights reports. Also I know I have the chance use JavaScript events to handle reporting personally, but I cannot since I am using iframe version of the button.

Also, is there a way for the Facebook fan page admin (the one that my like button links to) to see that detail exactly? e.g. "xx number of clicks generated with like button from this site (or app--which the like button is tied ?)"

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Facebook insights are far from being complete.

If I where you, I would track like events, and visits from like using an analytic tools like Google Analytics. This is what I do for my website, and the website of the company I am working for.

However, Facebook insights can give you complementary metrics (age, gender...).

Regards

Antoine

Comment: since i use iframe version ga do not work (actually their tracker is bound to the fbml events)

Answer (score 1):

Why use iframe if it is limiting you from doing what you need to do? Use XFBML or HTML5 versions and use the event handler to do an AJAX call to your server. Kinda like, Dr it hurts when I hit my thumb with a hammer, and the Dr says don't hit your thumb.

Comment: imho client side event handling should not be the only option; e.g. it would be nice if i could get some reports from the insights page, grouped by like buttons (not whole domain as it is now)

Comment: ok then, sigh, continue hitting your thumb with a hammer and use the iframe that doesn't do what you say the HTML5 and XFBML versions can.

Comment: Your end result is to make it work, so why say you cannot use something that works?

Comment: of course if there is no way i'll go with xfbml, but for now it's extra work for me (it messes css on the page). but be careful that xfbml and iframe differ only in how we handle the event on client side of our application. however my question is more than that; all requests go to facebook (whether it's iframe of xfbml) and if facebook can give you that report it's still ok for me. so to sum up: if facebook can give that report, i'll go with whatever i want, if not i have to capture events myself. only then the choice is to use iframe or xfbml (which will be xfbml apparently)

Comment: of course, none of the answers did help about anything. besides, you asked a question (i.e. "Why use iframe if it is limiting you from doing what you need to do?") rather than giving an answer :)

Comment: The answer is if there's no need to use an iframe which is limiting you from accomplishing the task, don't use it.  This is the reason Facebook has THREE options for you to use. Use an option that allows you to use the ref tags. Since you have not given any useful reason as to why the HTML5 version doesnt work for your situation, then simply change to it.

Comment: your 'answer' was already something i had mentioned that i was aware in the question. i am sorry but this is not an acceptable answer, not even an answer, imho.

Comment: Did you change your code to a non-iframe version in which you can use the ref tag?  As you pointed out, this is the answer to your question. The ref tag will allow you to track where the clicks came from.

Comment: If it is the answer then let me accept my question as answer, right? Since I mention (and emphasize that I *know*) that "Also I know I have the chance use JavaScript events to handle reporting personally".

Answer (score 0):

As Antoine says, you can track your likes with Google Analytics. I don't know about insights though.

Here's more info on how to track likes with GA:
http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/how-to-track-tweets-facebook-likes-and-more-with-google-analytics/

Comment: since i use iframe version ga do not work (actually their tracker is bound to the fbml events)

Answer (score 0):

Use [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

Comment: This should work in iframe pretty good. Likely you have some mistakes in your code.

Comment: no, it is mentioned in the documentation of like button that events do not work in iframe version of the like button